# I am writing a REST API using libcurl library in C language to login to my web page

Tags: php, c, libcurl

I am writing a REST API using libcurl library in C language to login to my web page.but every time I am getting 401 Unauthorized error. below is the code

```
int main(int argc, const char* args[])
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    struct curl_slist *header = NULL;
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {      
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://samplewebpage.com/rest/api/2/issue");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);       
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);      
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);      
        header = curl_slist_append(header, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");   
        header = curl_slist_append(header, "Authorization: Basic ");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, header);        
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "SharedIP:SharedIP@123");       
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
        /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */       
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_slist_free_all(header);
        /* Check for errors */
        if (res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: error %d %s\n", res,
                curl_easy_strerror(res));
        /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    curl_global_cleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that the authentication actually works with a real web browser?

Comment: Unrelated, but you really don't want these code: `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE); curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); `

Comment: @ChrisTurner yeah it's working fine

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a mix of do-it-yourself and let libcurl do it, both only half way.

### Yourself

You can add the HTTP authorization header yourself, but this is not a valid such header:

```
header = curl_slist_append(header, "Authorization: Basic ");
```

You're missing the base64("user:password") part that follows "Basic". Similar to this:

```
header = curl_slist_append(header, "Authorization: Basic aWFtOm15OjtzZWxm");
```

### let libcurl do it

Then you **don't** pass on the `Authorization:` header manually and instead ask libcurl to deal with the authentication. You do that by setting the `CURLOPT_USERPWD` option like you already do - but in your case you ruin it by your own custom (broken) header that overrides that internally generated header.

Comment: i tried with base64 encoding as well but didn't work.

Comment: i removed my header and passing CURLOPT_USERPWD. But still facing the issue

Comment: well, then maybe that's not how you're supposed to authenticate to this service?

Comment: do we have any other option also to authenticate?

Comment: Numerous. Several different HTTP methods, but it can also be form+cookies etc. Just blindly guessing will be tedious...

Comment: if you have one or two specific options please suggest.

Comment: If you get a 401 response back, that tells what auth it wants.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for reply, as i am new to this.most of the things in log is new to me.

Comment: < HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Date: Mon, 11 Feb 2019 03:58:54 GMT
< Server: Apache
< x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=8EAF9C77B57FD187DD660ACF66692851; Path=/LicenseReportingApplication; Secure; HttpOnly
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
< Content-Length: 4447 <
* schannel: client wants to read 4447 bytes
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 2491 length 17408
* schannel: encrypted data got 1994
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 4485 length 17408* schannel: decrypted data length: 4447
* schannel: decrypted data added: 4447